# How to pass arguments to a file which the locations to switch in the shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I have a shell script which takes an location input from a text file. I had loop in the script to read line(location) and change directory to the location and list the files.

In the below the location directory "switch" changes because this location may not exists on the all the servers. I have to pass this directory as an argument to the file and pass this location to the script.

locations.txt has below content.
/usr/test/home/process_file/switch/process.txt

shell script:

```
for i in `cat locations`;
do
        echo $line
        cd $i
        if [ -d "$i" ]
        then
                cd $i
                pwd
                ls -ltr
        else
                exit
        fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Storing a filename in a file seems a little inefficient.

[Don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

`cd` will return non-zero if the directory does not exist.

```sh
while IFS= read -r dir; do
    if cd "$dir" 2>/dev/null; then
        pwd
        ls -ltr
    else
        echo "no such directory: $dir"
    fi
done < /usr/test/home/process_file/switch/process.txt
```

Comment: I have almost 5 locations in the file and the path that i mentioned is one of them. one of the directories "switch" will change on the remote servers. So i will need to pass this directory as an argument to the file to be able to match the location on the server.

./test "directory_name"